# Gulp - Create a minified library with correct module.exports

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a library in node that has the following structure

```
/src
index.js
```

With all the library files inside `/src`. The `index.js` is the entry point. I can normally use this as

```
var MyLibrary = require('./my-library/index');
```

Now, I want to contact this library into a single file (with all required libraries included as well). It should include all the libraries needed. This is what I have so far:

```
browserify(serverPath + serverEntry)
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('server.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildPath));
```

The file is "created", but when I include it, I get a bunch of errors. When I study the file, there are multiple `exports`, and not a single point of entry.

Comment: Why do you want to minify node.js code?

Comment: Okay, minify is a bit excessive. I'll remove that. What I specifically want is to just get one file

Comment: I've never seen browserify used in this way, I'm not surprised to see it not working. The goal of browserify is to create an output that is usable in the browser, which means built-in modules that aren't available to the browser will either fail or be replaced by browser-compatible alternatives.